# If i download a pic in telegram secret chat on a public wifi then can hacker see the photo?

Tags: wifi, telegram

I downloaded a sensitive pic on telegram's secret chat which contained important details on public wifi, can anyone on the same wifi see what i downloaded and saved in my gallery?

Answer (score 2):

> I downloaded a sensitive pic on telegram's secret chat which contained
> important details on public wifi, can anyone on the same wifi see what
> i downloaded and saved in my gallery?

No, of course not. Telegram uses end to end encryption along with server-client encryption for cloud chats. Being on the same network alone shouldn't allow an attacker to get to it. The attacker would need code running on your phone with storage permission to get the image from Telegram secret chat.